# How to advoid repeating command twice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that sorts an array of JS objects by values. The function takes a key that it uses to do the sort with. Once it has all the values the function orders the results in asc or desc order, this is where I'm using the repeated code. The only differance is ">, <"  signs.

Here is the code..., How can I rewite this to be move clean and not repeat the code?

Repeated Command:
results[0].sort( (a, b) => ( a[ this.orderBy ] > b[ this.orderBy ] ) ? 1 : -1 )

```
      if( this.orderBy ) {
        results = this.order === 'asc' ? 
        results[0].sort( (a, b) => ( 
          a[ this.orderBy ] > b[ this.orderBy ] ) ? 1 : -1 ):
        results[0].sort( (a, b) => ( 
          a[ this.orderBy ] < b[ this.orderBy ] ) ? 1 : -1 );
      }
```

Comment: You could move the condition inside your sort's callback [like so](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-boyd-2n9ie?file=/src/index.js:0-213), but whether this is 'cleaner' or not is debateable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
const inversionFactor = this.order === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;

results = results[0].sort( (a, b) =>
    a[ this.orderBy ] < b[ this.orderBy ] : -1 * inversionFactor : 1 * inversionFactor
);
```

**Edit:**
There is an issue in your current approach in that you are not accounting for the case where the two values are equal. Here is an approach that takes that into account and avoids duplication.

```
// this is a reusable function and can go outside of other functions
const compareBy = (prop, invert) => (a, b) => {
    if (a[prop] === b[prop]) { return 0; } 
    return (a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : 1) * (invert ? -1 : 1);
};

results = results[0].sort(compareBy(this.orderBy, this.order === 'desc'));
```